# How are NAT rules processed in Vyatta?

Tags: networking, router, nat, vyatta

I am setting up a Vyatta router to replace my pfSense box that died. As I setting up the NAT rules I am not sure how they are processed.

Are Vyatta's NAT rules processed in the order of the list until the first match?

I have several rules that are destination rules for things like Zimbra and OpenVPN.

But at the bottom of my NAT rules I have a source NAT rule that defines anything coming from my subnet `10.0.0.0/24` should be NAT'd to my second usable public IP address.

So if I needed a specific NAT rule like one for my Zimbra server which sits on the third usable public IP would that need to BEFORE the general NAT rule?

Answer (score 1):

Rules are processed in accept numerical order. If Rule 1 processes and agrees with statement, then statement is applied. If Rule 1 is false, then rule is not applied and moves on to Rule 2.